# Saving JTable Values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

I'm currently programming Yahtzee and I'm in the process of changing the player names. For this I use an extra form in which there is a `JTable` and a `JButton`.

Depending on the variable number of players in the table, an entry will be created where you can change the name. Only the second column should be editable - this also works.

However, I have no idea how to make it possible to add the contents from the second column to an `ArrayList` at the push of a button so that I can continue to use them.

Here is the implementation of my custom `TableModel`

```
public class SpielerBenennungTableModel implements TableModel {

    private int spielerAnzahl = 0;    
    private ArrayList<TableModelListener> Listener = new ArrayList<TableModelListener>();

    public SpielerBenennungTableModel(int spielerAnzahl){        
        this.spielerAnzahl = spielerAnzahl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return spielerAnzahl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int arg0) {
        if(arg0 == 0){
            return "Spieler";
        }else{
            return "Eigener Name";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        if(arg1 == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        if(arg1 == 0){
            return "Spieler: " + (arg0+1);
        }else{
            return rowData[arg0][arg1];    
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {         
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        Listener.add(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
         Listener.remove(arg0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Swing? Do you have an action listener for your button? Do you know how to read a value from a text box?

Comment: Yeah, I´m using a JTable. I know all of these things. The only thing I don´t know is how to get the text entries out of the table to safe them in an ArrayList.

Comment: Use the table's [`getValueAt(row,column)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt-int-int-) method.

Comment: This is where I'm struggeling. How can I create a loop which safes all column values in an ArrayList?

Comment: Use table's [`getRowCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount--) method to know how many rows to loop over.

Comment: When is the content in the row available? After it is typed? I don't update the Table, I just add the Strings into the rows

Comment: getValueAt will return whatever is in the row/col at the time it is called. So if you can see the name in the field, then getValueAt will return it.

Comment: I will try it - thank you!

Comment: Something like that. What should the GetValueAt method in the TableModel look like? I mean, the first column is fixed, but what do I return else?
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        if(arg1 == 0){
            return "Spieler: " + (arg0+1);
        }else{
            return this.getValueAt(i, 1);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

In your `SpielerBenennungTableModel` you need an object to hold the data you display. We will be using a `List<String[]>` that should look like this (I named it `rows`):

```
[
  ["Spieler: 1", "Bob"],
  ["Spieler: 2", "John"]
]
```

every time you change a value, the `setValueAt` method is called and will update the `List<String[]>` with the correct value.

Then when you use the `getValueAt` method, it will read from this same `List<String[]>`

```
class SpielerBenennungTableModel implements TableModel {

    private int spielerAnzahl = 0;
    private ArrayList<TableModelListener> Listener = new ArrayList<TableModelListener>();

    // this will hold the data for every rows
    private List<String[]> rows;

    public SpielerBenennungTableModel(int spielerAnzahl){
        this.spielerAnzahl = spielerAnzahl;

        // initialize the list so that all rows are
        // ["Spieler: n", ""]
        rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<spielerAnzahl; i++) {
            this.rows.add(new String[] { "Spieler: " + (i+1), "" });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return spielerAnzahl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return col == 0 ? "Spieler" : "Eigener Name";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return col == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return rows.get(row)[col];
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        rows.get(row)[col] = value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        Listener.add(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        Listener.remove(arg0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn´t help me. The question is for the interface. My table is using a TableModel and this model contains the getValueAt method which need a return statement.

if(arg1 == 0){
            return "Spieler: " + (arg0+1);
        } ... and here I need the case for the second column. Here I have to return the content of the table. Am I right?

Comment: I modified the answer, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems like it isn´t the right answer. My IDE wants to create a new variable for "rowData" - what should I do?

Comment: can you add the code of your TableModel to your question?

Comment: I added my TableModel.

Comment: Have a try now.

Comment: rows - type list does not take parameters

Comment: If you are not going to add or remove players, you can set it final.

Comment: check your imports, you are probably importing `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`

Comment: Oh - thank you for your work! I will try it out now